# Node js - errors when fetch() called: net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server, fetch-api

I'm trying to have the client send a fetch request and have the server (locally hosted) respond with the message "hello from server".

Here is my code

Server-side:

```js
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')

const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
    
    handleRequest(req,res).then(e => {
      if(e){
        //handle all request that aren't for static files
        if(e.req.url == '/test'){
          e.res.writeHead(200)
          e.res.write('hello from server')
        }else{
          e.res.writeHead(404)
        }
        e.res.end()
      }
    })

})

server.listen(3000)

function handleRequest(req,res){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    //I left out this code cause it doesn't matter, 
    //i just simplified it below
    //if request is not for a static file, resolve({req: req, res: res})
    //else resolve(null) and serve file
  })
}
```

Client-side:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn')
const messageFromServerHeader = document.getElementById('message-from-server-header')

btn.onclick = () => {
    fetch('/test').then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
}
```

When I run the code and click the button, I get this error in chrome:

> GET http://localhost:3000/test net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)

and this error in FireFox:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

The server has no problems serving the static files, there's only an issue when the fetch request is made. From the research I've done, I found some resources that say the "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" header could be the issue, but I don't know how to change that, or if that's even the problem in my case.

Also, when I checked the response headers on the server-side, chunkEncoding was set to false, but in the network tab on chrome once the response was sent, transfer-encoding was set to chunked.

Does anyone know the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I set the content type to `application/JSON` and called `JSON.stringify()` on the message I wanted the server to respond with.

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON' });
res.write(JSON.stringify('hello from server'));
res.end();
```

And then I parsed the data on the client side:

```
fetch('/test')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data) //"hello from server"
  })
```

This fixed all errors